# Delete multiple files with regex

Tags: delete

I have folder with sub-folders with same files, for example:

```
 dsc_9660__content_w.jpg
 dsc_9660__content.jpg
 dsc_9660__h70.jpg
 dsc_9660__small.jpg
 dsc_9660.jpg
```

Suffix - is different sizes of images.

How to delete all files with suffix like this:`__[a-zA-z0-9].(png|jpg|jpeg)`?
And keep only original images without suffix as `dsc_9660.jpg` in my example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**find**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/find.1posix.html) command with its `-regex` switch or `-iregex` (case insensitive), change your regex to `.*__[a-zA-z0-9_]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)` and use the `-delete` option to delete the matched file:

```bsh
find . -type f -regextype "posix-egrep" -iregex '.*__[a-zA-z0-9_]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$'
```

You can use other types of `-regextype` (which is worked) in place of "posix-egrep" like:
 "posix-extended" or "posix-awk".

```bsh
-regex pattern
    File  name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search.  For
    example, to match a file named './fubar3', you can use the regular expression '.*bar.'  or '.*b.*3',
    but not 'f.*r3'. The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expres‐
    sions, but this can be changed with the -regextype option.

-iregex pattern
    Like -regex, but the match is case insensitive.

-regextype type
    Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later on the
    command line. Currently-implemented types are emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-basic,
    posix-egrep and posix-extended.

-delete
    Delete files
```

At the end add `-delete` switch to command to deleting matched files:

```bsh
find . -type f -regextype "posix-egrep" -iregex '.*__[a-zA-z0-9_]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$' -delete
```

---

```
.*__[a-zA-z0-9_]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)
```

- The `.*` matches everything before `__`
- The `__` matches double underscores.
- The `[a-zA-z0-9_]*` matches all alphanumeric and a single underscore `_` characters. The `*` means this class of characters can be zero length.
- The `\.` matches a single dot. To match a dot (`.`) literally you need to escape it within the regular expression using a backslash; without escaping, it matches any single character.
- In the `(png|jpg|jpeg)`, pair of parentheses makes it as a group of matches. Will match `png` or (`|`) `jpg` or `jpeg`.
- The `$` anchor, matches the end of string (or file names in this case)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/84GILTHuJpy-oFGj) and [test on files](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9699664/)

---

Comment: That image... from Debuggex? Cool!

Comment: @pepoluan Yeah, just write your regex and click "Embed on StackOverflow" link (top right corner of box). you can find more on [Regular expressions converting into a diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10334431/4023950)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd <dir>
find . -type f -iname \*__*.jpg -delete
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below command,

```
cd <dir>
find . -type f -iname \*.jpg -delete
```

-type----> enter the type of the file ( __[a-zA-z0-9].(png|jpg|jpeg) )and make use of the command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your command you are deleting **All** .jpg files!!

Comment: The code in the code box appears to delete all the jpg files in the directory - I'm not sure that's actually helpful! Also, I'm not quite clear what the following line actually means (& I do use find...) as -type f indicates the "type of file" as a regular file, you can't just replace it with a regex or add one to it..